# Injective objects and "injective on elements" in Awodey's Category Theory

Tags: logic, category-theory

In the exercises to Ch.3 of Awodey's *Category Theory*, p. 72, he writes:

> 8. Dualize the notion of projectivity to define an *injective* object in a category. Show that a map of posets is monic if and only if it is injective on elements. Give examples of both an injective and a non-injective poset.

The definition of an injective object is clear to me. However, I don't get what he means by

> Show that a map of posets is monic if and only if it is injective on elements.

I mean, *objects* are said to be injective, not maps. So what the property "injective on elements" means here? I guess it just means ordinary set-theoretical injectivity and thus has *nothing to do* with injective objects at all, right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your guess is correct, the second case of the word 'injective' simply means it's an injective function. The terms *injective object* and *projective object* come from homological algebra, where these properties are useful to determine properties of exact sequences of modules or abelian groups; there's a reason why the words are used, but for the purposes of Awodey's book you can think of them as being unrelated.